# How to wrap PHPUnit to control command line reporting?

Tags: php, phpunit

So I've got a lot of PHPUnit tests (they are actually Selenium tests running as PHPUnit tests). When I run them from the command line, I get this sort of reporting as the tests complete:

```
..E..F..E.FF...
```

Then I have to wait until all the tests finish running before it will tell me the errors and what failed. I would like to be able to control this so I can do some more useful reporting. For example:

```
testLogin ....... passed
testFoobar ...... failed
    - Failed asserting that foo = true on line 123
testBazbat ...... passed
```

How can I get control over how PHPUnit displays the results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHPUnit has a few command line parameters to control the output format. The most useful ones for your are --testdox and --tap

They work like this:

```
]> phpunit --tap FooTest.php 
TAP version 13
not ok 1 - Failure: FooTest::test_add
  ---
  message: fark
  severity: fail
  ...
ok 2 - FooTest::test_exists
ok 3 - FooTest::test_show_html
ok 4 - FooTest::test_show_array
ok 5 - FooTest::test_show_empty
ok 6 - FooTest::test_find
1..6


]> phpunit --testdox FooTest.php 
PHPUnit 3.5.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Foo
 [ ] test add
 [x] test exists
 [x] test show html
 [x] test show array
 [x] test show empty
 [x] test find
```

As you can see --testdox does not show the failure reason, its ment to be used like a kind of specification generator. But --tap comes pretty close.

And you can always write your own test listener - a custom class that implements PHPUnit_Framework_Testlistener interface (has methods like startTest, endTest, addFailure, addError etc; the names are pretty self-explanatory, respective code will be called for events that happen when your testsuite runs).

Such code is hooked up into phpunit using the xml configuration file.

One good example of such custom listener can be viewed here: http://raphaelstolt.blogspot.com/2010/06/growling-phpunits-test-status.html

Comment: Thanks. That's really helpful. Could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by "test listener" and "loader"? That might be where I want to go with it, but I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: I edited the answer with more details about test listeners. Custom test loader is actually not relevant at all for your issue, so I removed that part.

Comment: `--tap` does not display any useful information on errors. IMO `--verbose` is more useful.

Answer (score 1):

use the

```
--printer path/to/MyTestListener
```

option to point to your custom MyTestListener class
http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions

or it can be set in your phpunit.xml config file with the **printerClass** property

see http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration

Here's the instructions how to make your own printer class
http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.examples.SimpleTestListener.php

If you don't want to start from scratch just rename and modify the default printer
https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/PHPUnit/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want pretty HTML report pages, try to use [phing](http://phing.info)'s `phpunitreport` task. For Screenshots, see [my blog entry](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/visualizing-phpunit-runs.htm). Very helpful for larger test suites.