# How many open files in PHP?

Tags: php, unit-testing, file-io

Is there a function in PHP to query the number of open files?

Sort of like `memory_get_usage()` but for open files.

I'm running the unit test suites for Zend Framework.  The problem is that after it gets through the tests for Zend_Search_Lucene, subsequent tests start failing.  But if I skip the Zend_Search_Lucene tests, all the test suites succeed.

I'd like to prove that Zend_Search_Lucene (or any other test suite) is opening too many files and not cleaning up after itself.  I thought PHP might have a function to simply report how many files are open.  But after 20 minutes of searching the PHP manual and Google, I can't find any such function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such function in PHP.

But there are alternatives. If you are running linux/unix/OSX, then running lsof from command line can give you that information.

This could be combined with a custom Test listener for PHPUnit - I described the approach under a different question - [How to wrap PHPUnit to control command line reporting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937046/how-to-wrap-phpunit-to-control-command-line-reporting/3939872#3939872)

PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener interface has methods like startTest(), endTest(), startTestSuite(), endTestSuite(). You could execute a shell_exec call to lsof from those methods and print out the interesting numbers before and after every test/testsuite.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll keep it in mind for the future.  This time, I just ran `system("lsof -p ".getmypid())` in the tearDown() of the test I thought was the culprit, and I found that it was.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do, is to [unregister](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-unregister.php) the default stream handler and then [register](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php) my own in which I'd provide an implementation for [`stream_open`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php) that keeps an internal counter.

Answer (score 0):

These two might do what you are looking for:

- [`apd_dump_regular_resources`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.apd-dump-regular-resources.php) — Return all current regular resources as an array
- [`apd_dump_persistent_resources`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.apd-dump-persistent-resources.php) — Return all persistent resources as an array

Iit's a wild guess though because I never used APD (it's PECL), so it might be *resources* does not refer to the actual `resource` type. Unfortunately, I couldnt find any documentation showing output.